# Spring not loading properties from external config file properly

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an internal *application.yml* file located in the classpath resources with the following fields:

```
redis:
  hostname: localhost
  port: 6379
  database: 0
  password:
```

There is an external config file: *config.properties*. It defines some fields to be overridden in my server context. File *config.properties*:

```
redis.hostname = db.example.com
redis.password = my_password
```

The application fails to start because it is not able to read the redis.port property in the config file. My doubt is that spring is not retaining fields of a property source(*redis*) completely if it has already found some fields defined in the external file(hostname, password in this case).

I am running the application using the following command:

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=file:///home/username/config.properties application.jar
```

How do I make spring properly override the internal configuration file so that it only overrides the extra properties(redis.hostname, redis.password) but still retain the other fields defined in the internal file(like redis.port, redis.database) but not defined in the external file?

P.S: I know this is what is happening because when I add the *redis.port=6379* property in the external config file, the applications works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Read the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

> Config locations are searched in reverse order. By default, the configured locations are `classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/`. The resulting search order is the following:
>
> ```
> file:./config/
> file:./
> classpath:/config/
> classpath:/
> ```
>
> When custom config locations are configured by using `spring.config.location`, they **replace the default locations**. For example, if `spring.config.location` is configured with the value `classpath:/custom-config/,file:./custom-config/`, the search order becomes the following:
>
> ```
> file:./custom-config/
> classpath:custom-config/
> ```

Step 2: Specify the correct value:

```
-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/,file:///home/username/config.properties
```

Comment: The application *seems* to start properly with the trace logging level set as can be seen in the prodigious amount of logs generated, which is very strange since the default is always DEBUG and I have explicitly set it to INFO in the internal application.yml file. So I am not sure if it is working in my case.

Comment: Spring boot 1.x and 2.x have different behaviors. Spring boot 1.x didn't replace "default locations"

Answer (score 0):

```
file:
```

and

```
classpath:
```

need to be specified when you are binding the configuration in your code. When you are specifying the -D parameter, you could pass address of the property file relative to the jar file location.